# Prevent the triggering of a click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few smaller div nested within a larger div. 1 specific small div `#small`and the large div `#large` have jQuery `click()` event handler attached to them.

**Problem:** How do I make it such that when a click happens inside that one smaller nested div, the `click()` handler of the larger div is not fired, only the one for the smaller div is? The `click()` of the larger div must still fire if the click occurs in the *other* smaller divs.

**HTML**

```
<div id="large">
    <div id="small"></div>
    <div id="small_2"></div>
    <div id="small_3"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#large").click(function() {
    console.log('large');
}

$("#small").click(function() {
    console.log('small');
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$("#small").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('small');
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/